# React-Router V4 - server rendering works only on one machine

Tags: reactjs, react-router, server-rendering, mern

I'm building a MERN project with server-rendering. When someone pull the project (eiter on server or local) he gets this error:

`TypeError: (0 , _reactRouter.createServerRenderContext) is not a function`

But on my machine it works properly, witouth errors.

Also, I'm using react-router version 4.0.0-**alpha**.5 - maybe alpha version is the problem?

Comment: make sure your package.json links to the specific version. { react-router: 4.0.0-alpha.5 } not { react-router: ^4.0.0-alpha.5 }